# WatchKit swipe right on table to show context menu

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, apple-watch

Is there a way to have on WatchKit table a swipe gesture recognition to show a menu of options, like in the UITableView on iPhone, when swiping right to left, you can show options like Delete, mark or more options.

In the Apple Watch included Mail app it is possible to swipe from right to left and two options are shown, More and Delete.